# Entity Framework version 6. Code First Model - Is there any way use two different application production and testing code with one database

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, windows-forms-designer

I am stuck with  issue in Entity Framework version 6. Code First Model - Production system in windows application . let me explain.

Production Server- running application .exe has four different class meaning four different table with sync production application, working fine.

Now I am going to add one more model same as table for upgrade software with same database now issue start here "**if i update-database with entity framework then my production system will be down** because database will be changed over database server, **update one more table and entity framework structure has been changed over server**. how to avoid this situation.

can't take database backup on local system for testing because my client is not allow me to take data.

what I want, my production exe should be work as it is
Update exe also work with same database.

please suggest how to achieve that target.

Comment: While you might not be able to take a back up of data, can you at least take a copy of the data structure?  And hate to tell you how to run your operation but honestly if the customer is putting that much restriction on you they will either have to deal with the system being compromised during development cycles or perhaps just walk away.  Honestly sometimes users just aren’t worth the headache

Comment: Could you maybe create a second database catalog on the same server as live DB then use a development only connection string for your purpose?